# Is there a shortcut for assigning a variable to a pointer without creating the variable in a separate line first?

Tags: go

If I have a struct like this:

```
type Message struct {
    Id      int64
    Message string
    ReplyTo *int64
}
```

And then if I did create an instance of this struct like this:

```
var m Message
m.Id = 1
m.Message = "foo bar yo"

var replyTo = int64(64)
m.ReplyTo = &replyTo
```

Then it would work.

But I was wondering if there was a shortcut for the last step?

I tried doing something like:

```
m.ReplyTo = &int64{64}
```

But it did not work.

Comment: Yeah you can't assign to an int pointer unless you already have an int stored in memory somewhere which isn't the case here (you're assigning that memory address to the value, not the value itself). Personally, I don't think you should be using a pointer in your struct. Unless your actual program differs substantially from your example there is no reason for it. It's bad for application performance too. In the example you gave you're doubling the memory required to store those values, one word for the int, another to store the address as a value on your struct.

Comment: I have to do it for MySQL and NULL values. sql.NullInt64 works but I'm not sure if it works with sqlx library where you can just take a struct and pass it ass parameter for prepared statements.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. This is when you're trying to instantiate the type directly then, right? Like when you unmarshal a row into an instance of type `Message` that value gets set correctly, right?

Comment: This is duplicate. (Too lazy to look up the original).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can because the value is a primitive and attempting to do it in one shot like the below would be a syntax error. Its attempting to get an address of a **value** so it wouldn't be possible. At least I am not aware of a way where its possible.

```
someInt := &int64(10) // would not compile
```

The other alternative you have is to write a function to return a pointer to the primitive like the following:

```
func NewIntPointer(value int) *int {
  return &value
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about `new(int)`

Comment: @JimB but I don't think its possible to assign it a value. It would still be a two step process, something like `value := new(int); *value = 10` . I guess thats a little more elegant than assigning a temporary variable and getting the reference of that though.

Comment: It does assign a value, but it's always the zero value ;) sometimes that's all you need to ensure something's not nil.

Answer (score 1):

A tricky way to get int pointer without create new variable.

```golang
someIntPtr := &[]int64{10}[0]
```